When creating a 3d mesh in gmsh, I want to find the coordinates of the vertices of each of the surfaces in my volume using Python
For example, if I create a cube in gmsh, how can I find the vertices at the corners of each face?  I am writing a Python program and trying to use gmsh.model.getAdjacencies() for each surface to get the tags of the points on the surface and then getValues() to get the coordinates.
.
Here is my code:
import gmsh
current_2d = 0
gmsh.initialize()
meshfilename = "meshfile"
gmsh.model.add(meshfilename)
length = 30
meshed_shape = gmsh.model.occ.addBox(10, 15, 5, length, length, length)
# colleect points for each surface
gmsh.model.occ.synchronize()
volumes = gmsh.model.getEntities(dim=3)
last_volume_tuple = volumes[-1]
last_volume_index = last_volume_tuple[1]
physicalName = "block_Volume"
vol_tag = gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(3, [last_volume_index])
gmsh.model.setPhysicalName(3,vol_tag, physicalName)
print("vol_tag = ",vol_tag)
# make physical surfaces
surfaces = gmsh.model.occ.getEntities(dim=2)
total_2d = len(surfaces)
new_2d = total_2d - current_2d
new_surf_tuples = surfaces[-new_2d:]
# each surface tuple has 2 numbers.  The first number is the dimension (which is 2 for a surface)
# the second number is the index referring to a particular surface
for surface_tuple in new_surf_tuples:
    surf_tag = gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(2, [surface_tuple[1]])
    physicalName = "Block_Surf"+str(surface_tuple[1])
    gmsh.model.setPhysicalName(2, surf_tag, physicalName)
    volume_list, points_list = gmsh.model.getAdjacencies(2,surface_tuple[1])
    print("surface elementary tag ", surface_tuple[1], "points : ",points_list," volume ",volume_list)
    for point_tag in points_list:
        try:
            print( gmsh.model.getValue(0, point_tag, []))
        except:
            print ("point ",point_tag," was not found.")    
current_2d = total_2d

It works for 2 of the 6 faces on my cube, but I get tags that are out of range for the other 4 faces. I get the surface tags from the elementary volume tag.  I notice that if I get a list of points using gmsh.model.occ.getEntities(dim=1), I get a list of 12 tuples, but a cube does not have that many vertices.
